# Percentage of pre-tail Monero that has been mined compared to Bitcoin

Tags: tail-emission

At what approximate block height/date will the percentage of mined pre-tail Monero emission equal the same percentage percentage as Bitcoin?

Is there a spreadsheet or calculator that can easily help answer identify the percentage of pre-tail coin supply that will be mined as of a specific blockheight/date?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> At what approximate block height/date will the percentage of mined pre-tail Monero emission equal the same percentage percentage as Bitcoin?

This will happen at approximately February 11, 2017. At this date approximately 75.72% of the pre-tail Monero will be mined. In the spreadsheet it is marked as "Total Emission Crossover".

> Is there a spreadsheet or calculator that can easily help answer identify the percentage of pre-tail coin supply that will be mined as of a specific blockheight/date?

Yes [there is](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qXi7zUSIh7F6UuSuhOryyFbHEy_LJuym3I3neAga_2s/edit?pli=1#gid=239466694). 
For clarity, I have used this spreadsheet to answer your first question as well. Credits for the spreadsheet go to core-team member luigi1111.